# Replacing character in data frame with number based on contional information in each row

Tags: language-agnostic

For the below data I would like to use the allele variable to recode the rest of the data, as following : 
If  the first letter  in variable allele at specific row start with A  replace all  A with 1 for that row only. And if the row start with G in variable allele at specific row replace all  G with 1 for that row only. And if the row start with C  in variable allele at specific row start with T  replace all  T with 1 for that row only .  Then replace H with 0  ( in all the data frame) and the rest of the letters ( AGCT) with -1 for all the data frame.

```
    alleles x1  x2  x3  x4
1   A/G G   G   G   G
2   A/G G   G   G   G
3   A/C C   N   N   C
4   C/T T   N   N   T
5   C/G N   C   C   H
6   C/G C   N   N   C
7   C/T C   C   T   C
8   A/G G   G   A   G
9   A/G N   N   A   A
10  A/G G   G   N   G
11  C/T N   C   C   C
12  A/G N   A   A   A
```